# How to show a unique image for each checkbox item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

my MVC application has a few checkbox items, however, I need to show unique images for each checkbox item, each item is unique so a unique image should too.

Here's what I tried:

View(Index.cshtml):

```
//MULTIPLE CHECK BOX
for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxItems.Count; i++) //this line throws an exception (null)
{
    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.CheckBoxItems[i].ImageUrl)" />
    <div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CheckBoxItems[i].CBName)
        @Html.LabelFor(l => l.CheckBoxItems[i].CBIsSelected, Model.CheckBoxItems[i].CBName)

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => r.CheckBoxItems[i].CBIsSelected, false);
    </div>
}
```

Controller(HomeController.cs):

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ModelVariables model = new ModelVariables()
        {       
            CheckBoxItems = Repository.CBFetchItems()        
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Model(ModelVariables.cs):

```
  public class ModelVariables
{
    //CHECKBOX
    public List<Item> CheckBoxItems { get; set; } 
}


public class Item
{
    public string CBName { get; set; }
    public bool CBIsSelected { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

public static class Repository
{   
    public static List<Item> CBFetchItems()
    {
        return new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item(){  CBName = "Girls?" },
            new Item(){  CBName = "Dudes?" },
            new Item(){  CBName = "Animals?" },
            new Item() { ImageUrl  = "~/Assets/ass.PNG"}
        };
    }     
}
```

When you copy/paste this code and run it, you will get a null exception error.

Comment: You could start by telling us which line the error is on. (Additionally files in `App_Data` are blocked and won't be served, you need to put them in another directory)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen hey there, I updated question and added a comment next to the line where the exception is thrown, then I updated path by creating a new folder named 'Assets' but I still get the issue.

Comment: ...I didn't say the directory name was related to your current problem, it was just an FYI.

Comment: @ScuddleWuddles, Did you set `@model ModelVariables` in your view?

Comment: You will not get a `NullReferenceException` with the code you have shown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke hmm I'm getting one tho

Comment: I'll create a DotNetFiddle shortly to prove it :)

Comment: Your exception is probably thrown at `<img src="@Url.Content(Model.CheckBoxItems[i].ImageUrl)" />` because not all `Item` objects contain a value for `ImageUrl` (its not at the `for` line of code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke hey gj, tried and works, however, I need a unique image for each checkbox item, so I need image a, b, c, d, to go along with check box a, b, c, d, how do I implement that?

Comment: Just add an `ImageUrl` value for each `Item` - `new Item(){ CBName = "Girls?", ImageUrl  = "~/Assets/Girls.PNG" }, new Item(){ CBName = "Dudes?", ImageUrl  = "~/Assets/Dudes.PNG" }` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke nice and it worked, one last tiny thing: when I run the code, instead of images loading, I just get the path.. just like in the .net fiddle, a path is displayed hmmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one of your itens contains an image 
url, the others have a null value. You are probably getting the error when url.content is trying to process a null value.

**Edit2: Add code for possible solution**
Sorry, Url.Content can't accept empty string either, so previous edit wouldn't have worked.

I guess you need to put an if check in your razor code to handle no picture links.

```
if( Model.CheckBoxItems[i].ImageUrl != null ) {         
    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.CheckBoxItems[i].ImageUrl)" />
}
```

Comment: Added some code which you can try to see if this fixes your problem

Comment: Don't know what I was thinking earlier, but url.content doesn't accept empty strings either. So you will need to put a check in the razor for null url or make sure that every item will contain a picture link like what Stephen suggested in comments above

Comment: woa tried this and it worked beautifuly, Stephen had it aswell but his only displayed the url, yours actually loads the images, gj man you got it right!